# HighChart not rendering perfectly in IE8

Tags: javascript, orchardcms-1.6, dotnethighcharts

i integrated highcharts with Orchard1.6 everything was comes perfect but the problem is that the chart does not render perfectly in IE8, i dont know whether this is browser issue or i need to work out more for this here is the screen shot for that issue

[image]

anyone know the fix for this issue it would be more helpful
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the browser issue as and when i hear Chart and IE8 its like someone using myspace on Netscape. Who to blame!

The issue you are looking at is z-index of the tootltip if not let me know as you need to give us some more direct impact to this interface via jsfiddle or something so we can tinkerbin or play with it to get you right values.

Try to see if IE8 with chrome frame solves this issue or try compatibility mode to see if that helps. Most probably a css hack would solve this.

Try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TuMwJ/34/) for the issue reported on github [as an issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highchart) but closed now so one of the fiddles in there will help you solve this.

```
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
fill: #333333;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 16px;
line-height: normal;
text-align: left;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 141px;
```

Check the version and css you are loading

Comment: i cant give a direct impact because the data binding from db and also i integrated this to orchard1.6, i dont know as hw to present you. is there any other possible wat to give a good suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode and does it make any difference

Comment: yub thats works fine but the problem is only in the IE8 and lower version of IE.